# Premature Redo Log Switching in Oracle RAC

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What are the possible causes of premature redo log switching in Oracle other than reaching the specified file size and executing `ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE`?

We have a situation where some (but not all) of our nodes are prematurely switching redo log files before filling up. This happens every 5 - 15 minutes and the size of the logs in each case vary wildly (from 15% - 100% of the specified size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ixora.com.au/tips/tuning/log_switch.htm) says that it behaves differently in RAC.

> In a parallel server environment, the
>   LGWR process in each instance holds a
>   KK instance lock on its own thread.
>   The id2 field identifies the thread
>   number. This lock is used to trigger
>   forced log switches from remote
>   instances. **A log switch is forced
>   whenever the current SCN for a thread
>   falls behind the force SCN recorded in
>   the database entry section of the
>   controlfile.** The force SCN is one more
>   than the highest high SCN of any log
>   file reused in any thread.